# CMake variable names case sensitive?

Tags: cmake, case-sensitive

How does CMake treat variable names? Are they case sensitive?

If I use `FindFoo.cmake` with

```
find_package(Foo)
```

can I use `FOO_FOUND`, `Foo_FOUND` and `foo_FOUND`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

CMake variables are case sensitive. See [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#variables).

---

As a side note, commands are case insensitive, and their *arguments* are case sensitive. See [wiki](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Language_Syntax#Listfiles_contain_comments_and_commands.). Keywords like STATUS are case sensitive because they are arguments. Example:

```
message(STATUS foo)
MESSAGE(status foo)
```

outputs:

```
foo
statusfoo
```

the second marked as a warning (default message type).

Still regarding case sensitivity, take also a look to the [boolean variable section](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Language_Syntax#CMake_supports_boolean_variables.).

Comment: Ahh, I missed that page. "Variable names are case-sensitive" is even a quote.

Comment: @usr1234567 Somehow google doesn't score very high cmake 3.X documentation... One has basically to search specifying something like `site:https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/manual/`.

Comment: That's why I asked the question. Google will find it and then people get your link. Perfect!

Comment: So when all lower case symbol (foo and status in this case) is treated as a string?

Comment: @HelinWang Sort of, although I would recommend to quote any string you'd like to print

Comment: But why do sometimes different cases can be used without any error, e.g., GET_TARGET_PROPERTY and get_target_property can be interchanged?

Comment: @user5280911 `get_target_property` is a command and, as such (as I explained at the start of the second part of the answer) it is case insensitive. **Arguments and variables** are case sensitive instead.

Answer (score 8):

They **are** case sensitive.

Here an example:

```
set(foo 42)

MESSAGE( STATUS ${foo})
MESSAGE( STATUS ${Foo})
```

Output:

```
-- 42
--
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the documentation of FindFoo to find out what the correct `_FOUND` variable is. Or maybe use this tool someday:

https://youtu.be/BPgXuvPAl-8?t=659

Comment: CMake deamon is kind of off-topic, but it looks awesome. And you provide a Kate plugin. How cool is this?