# Building Google glog with CMake on Windows (failed)

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw32, glog

I need the glog library (https://github.com/google/glog) for a C++ project (Windows 10, Qt 5.10) and try to build it from sources using CMake. The CMake configuration process was succesful, the path to gflags is also set correctly.

After configurating glog with CMake, I tried to compile it with MinGW (command mingw32-make in the build folder). After 64%, the building process stopped with an error:

```
[ 64%] Linking CXX executable utilities_unittest.exe
libglog.a(symbolize.cc.obj):symbolize.cc:(.text+0x15f): undefined reference to `_imp__SymFromAddr@20'
libglog.a(symbolize.cc.obj):symbolize.cc:(.text$_ZN6google14SymInitializerC1Ev[__ZN6google14SymInitializerC1Ev]+0x2f): undefined reference to `_imp__SymSetOptions@4' 
libglog.a(symbolize.cc.obj):symbolize.cc:(.text$_ZN6google14SymInitializerC1Ev[__ZN6google14SymInitializerC1Ev]+0x51): undefined reference to `_imp__SymInitialize@12' 
libglog.a(symbolize.cc.obj):symbolize.cc:(.text$_ZN6google14SymInitializerD1Ev[__ZN6google14SymInitializerD1Ev]+0x12): undefined reference to `_imp__SymCleanup@4' libglog.a(demangle.cc.obj):demangle.cc:(.text+0x9e): undefined reference to `_imp__UnDecorateSymbolName@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles\utilities_unittest.dir\build.make:98: recipe for target 'utilities_unittest.exe' failed 
mingw32-make[2]: *** [utilities_unittest.exe] Error 1 
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:482: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/utilities_unittest.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]:
*** [CMakeFiles/utilities_unittest.dir/all] Error 2 
Makefile:159: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Do you have any idea how to fix it?

I already tried to enable the 
    CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS
option, but this did not solve the problem.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Someone at Google forget to add Dbghelp.lib to the linker library list.  Open CMakeLists.txt and add something like if(WIN32)
  target_link_libraries (Dbghelp)
endif (WIN32).

Comment: Do you have `dbghelp` library installed? What value of `HAVE_DBGHELP` variable in CMake cache (file `CMakeCache.txt` in the build directory)?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I think this is Windows DLL and import library should comes from WinSDK https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681400(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @VictorGubin: CMake code for `glog`  checks existence of `DbgHelp` library: https://github.com/google/glog/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L117, and, if found, performs appropriate linking. Probably, the check has failed for some reason.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Ok, I see it. check_library_exists (DbgHelp UnDecorateSymbolName "" HAVE_DBGHELP). I think it should be check_library_exists (Dbghelp UnDecorateSymbolName "" HAVE_DBGHELP) ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35023939/cmake-variable-names-case-sensitive

Comment: @VictorGubin: The first parameter to the macro `check_library_exists` is **library name**, which corresponds to the *file*. As files on Windows are case-insensitive, the case of the first parameter is indifferent. However, as this is not a pure Windows, but MinGW, so I am not sure.

Comment: @Tsyvarev MinGW, this is important note. I do suppose that something is wrong with the import library. Try to regenerate it as described at http://mirrors.zoreil.com/webclub.kcom.ne.jp/ma/colinp/win32/tools/dlltool.html

Comment: 1.) The value of 'HAVE_DBGHELP' in the file 'CMakeCache.txt' is empty: 'HAVE_DBGHELP:INTERNAL='. But it is already installed in the System32 folder. 2.) Changing DbgHelp to Dbghelp does not make a difference  3.) For which file should I regenerate the import library? Which .def file do you mean?

Comment: [dbghelp.def](https://reep.io/d/h2jf9kcsvg) It to late for link, [manual](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/cs1300/doc/mingwfaq.html) Managed with objdump approach. List of functions can be found in export table.

Comment: For Msys: dlltool --def dbghelp.def --dllname /c/Windows/System32/dbghelp.dll --output-lib libdbghelp.a

Comment: Ok, i created libdbghelp.a now. To which path should I copy this file? I tried to copy it to C:\MinGW\lib, but it has no effect to building glog (the same error occurs)

Comment: So, I just downloaded the last release [0.3.5](https://github.com/google/glog/releases/tag/v0.3.5) of glog which works fine.The problem seems to be somewhere in the current master branch, but since at least the last release compiles correctly, the problem is solved for me. Thanks for your help!