# Have troubles with the CMake build directory

Tags: cmake, doxygen

I have a very simple `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(Test_documentation)

find_package(Doxygen)
if (Doxygen_FOUND)
    find_file(DOXYGEN_PLANTUML_JAR_PATH
        plantuml.jar
        $ENV{PLANT_UML_JAR_PATH}
        /usr/share/plantuml
    )

endif (Doxygen_FOUND)
```

(I did have more but I stripped it down whilst trying to fix this issue).

I want to run a simple out-of-source build (on Windows - though I know one of those plantuml search path's is Linux-related).

```
PS D:\cmaketest> cmake D:\repos\My\far\away\project\Doc\CMakeLists.txt
....
-- Build files have been written to: D:/repos/My/far/away/project/Doc
```

Nothing gets written in `cmaketest` at all (and I want the build files to be written there and .\Doc to be unchanged.)

There are no other CMake-related files in ...\Doc.

What have I got wrong here as I want an out of source build and not for any of the build files to be in the source directory.

Comment: Do you actually run Doxygen? Also [CMake variables are case sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35023939/cmake-variable-names-case-sensitive) and the result variable is [`DOXYGEN_FOUND`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindDoxygen.html#variable:DOXYGEN_FOUND) in caps.

Comment: Doxygen *is* being found - but not used at present, but that's not the subject of the question.

Comment: It seems I don't understand the question at all. Please [edit] and give a [mre].

Comment: I have provided a minimal example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the -S (path to source) and -B (path to build) options.

ie.

```
 cmake -S D:\repos\path\to\my\far\away\project\Doc -B .
```

Will find the `CMakeLists.txt` in the Doc directory and build a tree in the current directory.